# Tikzexternalize not compling on Win7 TexStudio Texlive Install

Tags: windows, tikz-external

I am attempting to implement `\tikzexternalize` using a MWE.  I was able to successfully compile the MWE on a LinuxMint install with the same configuration.
On a Win7 installation I am unable to compile the MWE.

Configuration:
OS: WIn7; IDE:TexStudio2.8.8; TEXengine:texlive_150128wininstaller (sorry I cant find the version) Compiler:pdflatex 3.0.0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

TexStudio Configuration\commands\pdflatex :

> ```
> "P:\texlive\2014...\pdflatex.exe"  -src -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
> ```

When `\usetikzlibrary{external}` is `%` commented out the process exits normally.
When `\usetikzlibrary{external}` is included an error occurs and no `main-figure0.pdf` is generated.  A `main-figure1.md5` is generated in addition to `.log`, `.aux`, `.auxloc` and `main.pdf` files.

> ```
> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
> rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{m
> ain}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'main-figure0' (expec
> ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c
> alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name
> d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error 
> messages can be found in 'main-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to t
> ypeset the picture.
> ```

I have attempted several variations of `pdflatex` switches but now I'm just throwing things at it to see if anything will stick. Suggestions to troubleshoot on a Win7 system would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you compile from the command line?

Comment: I'm almost sure that on Windows you have to replace the `shell-escape` by `write18` option. Look for that.

Comment: Paul Gessler: I looked at your markups but I cannot tell how you formatted the text starting with "! Package tikz Error:".  Originally I incorrectly used blockquotes and it doesn't match my code section.  How do I create the correct format?

Comment: I thought it was fixed but misread the log file.  I changed the --shell-escape to --write18 running from command line.  Error unchanged.  I ran the functioning commented %\tikzexternalize code to check effect of the two different options.  With --write18 echo reports --write18 not recognized and .log shows "restricted \write18 enabled".  With --shell-escape process exits normally and .log shows "\write18 enabled".  Both methods produce main.pdf files.